# Moving many files from many directories using a script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm wanting to move many files, each of which are in their own directory, into one common directory. Each of the directories that these files are in have the same basename as the files. I've created a text fill listing all of these basenames. I then made a sript file written as:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 'cat basenames.txt'
do
        cd $i
        mv ${i}.html /c/Users/USER/directory1
        cd ..

done
```

When I run the script I get :

```
move.sh: line 4: cd: too many arguments
mv: cannot stat 'cat': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'all.txt.txt': No such file or directory
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I hope this isn't a school assignment.  First, as the answerer pointed out, 'cat bastename.txt' is a literal string.  What you intended was ``cat bastename.txt`` with backticks instead of single quotes (although the dollar sign and parentheses works as well) Also, entering echo $i in your loop to see what your code is actually doing is a good strategy as a first step in debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'cat basenames.txt'` with single quotes is a *string literal*, so your `for` loop is passing the whole thing to `cd`

Presumably you want to evaluate the command `cat basenames.txt` and pass the result, one at a time, to your loop body: that would require backticks

```
for i in `cat basenames.txt`
```

or the more modern and recommended syntax

```
for i in $(cat basenames.txt)
```

HOWEVER looping over the output of a `cat` command will be subject to word splitting and shell glob expansion - so really I'd recommend re-writing the loop as

```
while IFS= read -r i
do
        cd "$i"
        mv "${i}.html" "/c/Users/USER/directory1"
        cd ..

done < basenames.txt
```